# Datatable not searching when column has text and numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using [data tables](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) to display customer data.  It is working as expected apart from one issue.  I have an address column with Data like

```
4 Main Street
7 Main Street
10 Main Street
```

The search filter in the top right is not working when the column contain a combination of Numbers and Text.  If for example, I changed the data to

```
Four Main Street
Seven Main Street
Ten Main Street
```

then the search works as expected, however, this isn't how I want to display the data on the screen.  Note I am returning the address as a string from my Service.

My data tables setup is pretty simple as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function() {
            $('#customer').dataTable({
                bProcessing: true,
                sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("GetCustData", "Customer")'
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: in search box, u searching as `4` or `four` ? it only works as exact match.

Comment: I was typing 4 Main Street and it isnt working.  However Four Main Street does work however I want to display it as 4 Main Street

Comment: check this working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywsmw5wu/)